# ddrescue: reread only good sectors?

Tags: data-recovery, ddrescue

Before imaging the corrupted filesystem to a file on another hard drive, I decided to dry-run `ddrescue` (throwing rescued output to `/dev/null`) just to see how much data is unreadable:

```
# ddrescue -d -b 4096 -r 3 -f /dev/sda1 /dev/null sda1.log
```

In the end it took 3 days to finish.  Now I'm ready to make a real image, but I don't want to wait another 3 days until it finishes.  But, luckily because I have a logfile, is it possible to force `ddrescue` to rescue only the good sectors and do not touch bad ones?

Having read some documentation, I've came up with the following idea:

```
# ddrescue -d -b 4096 --fill=+ /dev/sda1 /mnt/sda1.img sda1.log
```

Will this work?  Is there another (preferred) way of rereading only good sectors?

Comment: I thought it didn't even try to reread at all by default... In fact, you told it to retry 3 times, `-r 3`. `-n` may also save time, although I guess it won't try to get as much data as possible.

Comment: So that's why I came up with the idea of using `--fill=+` option ("fill mode")

Comment: I don't think you can really read a bad sector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thoroughly reread `ddrescue` manual and found out the following option:

> `-m file`
>   `--domain-logfile=file`
>
> Restrict the rescue domain to the blocks marked as finished in the logfile *file*.  This is useful if the destination drive fails during the rescue.

So the invocation of `ddrescue` would look something like this:

```
# ddrescue -d -b 4096 -m sda1.log /dev/sda1 /mnt/sda1.img logfile2.log
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Quick edit 2018:

I use `ddrescue` sometimes, from some years ago, for rescuing hard-drive.

Something quicker than `dd` on hdd with really broken surfaces.

But `dd` is really safe and my first post stay true.

#### Original post

This is a **very bad idea**!!

> dry-run ddrescue, throwing rescued output to /dev/null

I'm talking about *Before imaging the corrupted filesystem to a file on another hard drive*...

As when a disk drive come to be corrupted, corruption are generally  growing **each time you try to access your drive**.

So **the** good way to rescue a broken drive is to **make an image by copying whole disk from begin to end in one uninterrupted operation!**. After that: unplug the disk drive and store them quietly. As: less  you touch the broken drive, more chance you have to restore something.

As each time mechanical access to broken material could make some more damages, the log you're become from your last operation **is not a reference** for knowing wich block are damaged *now*.

Here is a correct `dd` syntax for doing *raw dd read* even acros bad blocks.

```
dd bs=512 if=/dev/sdX of=/backuprepo/sdXBroken.img conv=noerror,sync
```

And, I let it work patiently.

Comment: Using `dd` without a block size (`bs`) set makes FSM sad.

Comment: "corrupted filesystem" - if he is lucky, he only has a software issue, not a hardware issue :)

Comment: stick to ddrescue - dd noerror sync corrupts data https://superuser.com/a/1075837/195171

Comment: @frostschutz, The link you point to is a ***very special case***, using virtual block devices and non-standard device block size. In all ***normal*** cases, trying to backup physical drive, using `conv=noerror,sync` is correct. For special case, you may have to explicitely specify `ibs` and `obs`. But that's no matter with the main subject of my answer: ***When things goes wrong don't try else than backup immediately***

Answer (score 1):

Knowing what ddrecue does, you should not use it to write to /dev/null while recovering data from broken disk, but to get "at least something" using writes into real image file.

Writing to /dev/null has sence e.g. if you want to know for brand-new disk if to return it to the store.

In this case, i would not use log file from "/dev/null attempt", but empty/new one, and then trying eventually more times couple of passes, depending how it does...

Comment: pretty sure this doesn't address the question of "Is there another (preferred) way of rereading only good sectors?"

Comment: @JeffSchaller: which means this should be a comment to the question -> not possible with the low points

Comment: To which the easy answer is: get more points! (By providing answers that people find useful and up-vote)